# KeyError with text based game

Tags: python

I am creating a text-based game where you make your way through a series of rooms and collect all the objects without running into the villain.

I keep getting a KeyError when trying to leave the starting room. But only if I entered an invalid direction. It's the only room that the error occurred in.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def show_instructions():
    # Print a main menu and commands
    print('Halloween Scavenger Hunt Text Adventure Game')
    print('Collect 6 items to win or lose them to the Dentist!')
    print('Move commands: go North, go South, go East, go West, Exit')
    print('Add to inventory: get', 'item')


show_instructions()


# define an inventory which will start off empty and start position
inventory = []
current_room = 'Town Square'


def show_status():
    # print the player current status
    print('-----------------------------------')
    print('You are in the', current_room)


show_status()


# A dictionary linking a room to other rooms
# and linking one item for each room except the Start room (Home) and the room containing the villain
rooms = {
        'Town Square': {'East': 'Grocery Store'},
        'Grocery Store': {'West': 'Town Square', 'North': 'Diner', 'South': 'Candy Shop', 'East': 'Bakery',
                          'item': 'Candy Corn'},
        'Candy Shop': {'North': 'Grocery Store', 'East': 'Cafe', 'item': 'Gummy Bears'},
        'Cafe': {'West': 'Candy Shop', 'item': 'Caramel Apple'},
        'Diner': {'South': 'Grocery Store', 'East': 'Ice Cream Parlor', 'item': 'Bubble Gum'},
        'Bakery': {'West': 'Grocery Store', 'North': 'Convenience Store', 'item': 'Popcorn Ball'},
        'Convenience Store': {'South': 'Bakery', 'item': 'Candy Bar'},
        'Ice Cream Parlor': {'West': 'Diner', 'item': 'Dentist'}
    }


def get_item():
    return rooms[current_room]['item']


while True:
    if current_room == 'Exit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    if current_room == 'Ice Cream Parlor':
        print('Game over! You lose all your sweets!')
        break
    if len(inventory) == 6:
        print('Congratulations! You won!')
        break
    print('Inventory', inventory)
    print('-----------------------------------')
    player_move = input("Enter your move: >")
    player_move = player_move.split()
    if player_move[0] == 'go':
        if player_move[1] in rooms[current_room]:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][player_move[1]]
            print('You are in the', current_room)
        else:
            print('You can not go that way!')
    item = get_item()
    if item in rooms[current_room]['item']:
        if item not in inventory:
            print('You see the', item)
        elif item in inventory:
            print()
        if player_move[0] == 'get':
            inventory.append(item)
            print(item, 'retrieved!')
        elif player_move[0] == 'Exit':
            current_room = 'Exit'
    else:
        print('Invalid move!')


print('Thanks for playing the game!')
```

Here's a screenshot of the error.

[image: First screenshot]

Comment: Please include textual content like error messages as plain text, not as images.

Comment: BTW there is no such thing as a "traceback error". A "traceback" is something that is attached to any kind of exception (such as the KeyError you are getting) which allows you to see where the error originated.

Comment: Ok..I guess a major edit took place. I did include a lot more information in my original post. BTW, I didn't know that I couldn't include actual pictures. I'm new to Python as well as this page. Sorry. I thought I could come here and people would be happy to help. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the last line in the error it says '**KeyError**' for '**item**'. What this means is that the key does not exist in the dictionary. The reason this is happening to you every time they enter a wrong move at the beginning is because the default room is **Town Square** which does not contain a key for **item** like the rest of the rooms so it will always fail when the function **get_item()** is called and the current room is still Town Square. 
See below

```
 'Town Square': {'East': 'Grocery Store'} # **NO ITEM KEY**
'Diner': {'South': 'Grocery Store', 'East': 'Ice Cream Parlor','item': 'Bubble Gum'
```

Comment: I get that. But I don't know how to fix it. I'm still new to Python. Which is why I was asking. They edited my question. I had all that info in before.